# Slide out text to left using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 3 icons on a page side by side.  What I am wanting is when a user hovers over the icon a small text span slides out to the left.

So that (no hover):
[IMG]

Hover (text slides out): SOME TEXT [IMG]

I am using this code for each icon:

```
<div class="cgs"><span class="cgstext">1. Connect</span><a href="#"><img src="images/cgs/connect70h.png" width="69" height="70" alt="Connect"></a></div>
```

If the icon was on the left and text on the right I would simply use jQuery animate to extended the outer div...but I'm not exactly sure what to do to make the span on the left slide out to the left.  I would prefer it to slide out gracefully and if it is in between 2 icons the space to expand gracefully (and contract gracefully on hover out) if possible.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough to get you there. I had to change your html, css, and add some js. Don't use a span because you can't set a width on it. Thus making `animate` useless. Instead I made it a div set to `inline-block`. You can then animate it properly. The rest is just javascript which it sounds like you know how to already anyhow.

Hover over an image.

http://jsfiddle.net/Mx2JS/3

```
<div class="cgs">
    <div class="cgstext">1. Connect</div>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/69x70" width="69" height="70" alt="Connect"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/69x70" width="69" height="70" alt="Connect"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/69x70" width="69" height="70" alt="Connect"></a>
</div>


$('a').hover( function() {
    $('div.cgstext').animate( { width:100 }, 500);
}, function() {
    $('div.cgstext').animate( { width:0 }, 500);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly do what I need (I need text to be beside each graphic) but it is close enough that I think I can get from here to what I need.  DIV (instead of SPAN) and INLINE-BLOCK was what I was needing.  Thanks!

Comment: BTW...thanks for the fiddle!  I forked it out to this which ALMOST does what I want (sliding back in not working, not sure why but will get it: http://jsfiddle.net/xbbBp/

Comment: Remove the `toggle` from second event handler. Also, because the `hover` event fires only when you are over the image you will also see a problem if you quickly mouse over all the images. The image might move out from under the mouse and trigger a close event. Try adding `nowrap` to your divs too. http://jsfiddle.net/xbbBp/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xbbBp/2/ - I saw that you were using `toggle` in addition to `animate` which is just going to mess stuff up. Also, you declared `display` on the text node twice which is going to screw up jQuery animate because it won't know the proper div style.